# Setting a dropdown for related objects in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need a dropdown in my events model to show all possible locations available to bind to the event in Django (using DRF). An event can have many locations, a location can have many events.

Unfortunately, I'm having issues when I set the `ModelChoiceField` on the Event model, with queryset `queryset=Location.objects.all()`, giving error:

> TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
>       metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

I'm assuming this is because, while Event Model is created *after* the Location Model, no data exists yet for Locations.

Then where can I define this dropdown field?

Locations Model:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
```

Events Model:

```
class Event(models.Model, forms.Form):
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location_id = models.IntegerField()
    locations = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Location.objects.all().order_by('location_name'), null=True)
```

EventLocation Join:

```
class EventLocation(models.Model):
    event_id = models.ForeignKey(Event, blank=True, null=True)
    location_id = models.ForeignKey(Location, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're mixing a Model and a Form when you declare the `Event` model like this:

```
class Event(models.Model, forms.Form):
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location_id = models.IntegerField()
    locations = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Location.objects.all().order_by('location_name'), null=True)
```

besides you're declaring `locations`  as a form's field instead of a Model  field.

In order to fix it, you must just declare the two models this way:

```
from django.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Event(models.Model):
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True)
```

Notice that you don't need to declare an intermediate model (EventLocation) for the relation between both Event and Location. Just declare a model field as a foreign key and Django will take care of it for you to create it.

Then if you go the the Event admin site, you'll see it's possible to choose a location from the dropdown input:

[image]

Comment: I still need to resolve the issue of getting locations in the events admin dropdown field

Comment: @Growler please check out the screenshot I've added

Comment: How are you adding that dropdown with locations though?

Comment: You just need to create some Location instances loading them using the admin site for the Location model. Then you go to Event admin and you'll see that dropdown, Django makes all that for you.

Comment: @Growler have you registered Event and  Location models in admin.py file?

Comment: Yes they are registered